# Can I access the binding at the moment of an exception in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

Say I have:

```
begin
  2.times do
    a = 1
    1/0
  end

rescue
  puts $!
  debugger
end
```

In this example, I want to get the value of `a`. If `a` is initialised in the `begin` block then I can access it when I rescue. However, in this example, `a` is block-local. Is there a way to get the binding at the moment of the exception, when I rescue?

Comment: I am not aware of a solution that works across rubies though I recall rbx had some neat `Backtrace` objects that could be helpful to you. Could you maybe expand on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @riffraff dunno if I can explain it better. I need to retrieve the value of a (in this example). For a real world scenario, imagine the 2.times block is an iterating block, retrieving one line from a CSV file, each time. At some point, at line number 203445 (of the CSV file) an exception happens. Now, I can go to that line num. in the CSV file to check whether that particular line is "OK". Or I can rescue and start a debugger session. At this point. I need to be able to see the binding, at the moment of the exception

Comment: thanks, the reason I was asking is that in similar situations I had the error management code inside the do block, so I had the chance to fix the single value and just keep going, which would seem to fit your scenario although it doesn't answer the original question, I'm afraid. The only thing I can suggest is that, if the error is not in native code, you can override raise/fail to store the caller binding, but it's only half a solution

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just put another `begin`,`rescue` block inside of the `do` block?

Comment: well, I could. It's not that I'm unable to check the value of a, or whatever other value I want. Maybe the title of my question is wrong. If I could rewrite it, it would start like "Is it possible to access the binding..." or, better, "Does Ruby provide me with the binding at the exception point?"

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the best answer (i.e. "no"). :-)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a hack possible to do this. It's not very nice though:

```
class Foo < Exception
  attr_reader :call_binding

  def initialize
    # Find the calling location
    expected_file, expected_line = caller(1).first.split(':')[0,2]
    expected_line = expected_line.to_i
    return_count = 5  # If we see more than 5 returns, stop tracing

    # Start tracing until we see our caller.
    set_trace_func(proc do |event, file, line, id, binding, kls|
      if file == expected_file && line == expected_line
        # Found it: Save the binding and stop tracing
        @call_binding = binding
        set_trace_func(nil)
      end

      if event == :return
        # Seen too many returns, give up. :-(
        set_trace_func(nil) if (return_count -= 1) <= 0
      end
    end)
  end
end

class Hello
  def a
    x = 10
    y = 20
    raise Foo
  end
end
class World
  def b
    Hello.new.a
  end
end

begin World.new.b
rescue Foo => e
  b = e.call_binding
  puts eval("local_variables.collect {|l| [l, eval(l)]}", b).inspect
end
```

Source: [How can I get source and variable values in ruby tracebacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106920/how-can-i-get-source-and-variable-values-in-ruby-tracebacks)